# Memory Continually Increasing When Iterating in Tensorflow Eager Execution

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to iteratively fit a function to data in a research application, where a large number of iterations are needed. In each function I am optimising on a variable. For simplicity I have recreated the problem in a minimal working example, excluding the function but the memory still climbs:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import psutil as ps
import gc
tf.enable_eager_execution()

for i in range (50000):
    w0=tfe.Variable(initial_value=np.ones((8,1)))
    print(ps.virtual_memory().percent)
```

The memory continually climbs given enough iterations. This would make sense from a graph building perspective as the graph would grow, however according to the docs in eager, you can release the memory as follows:

```
for i in range (50000):
    w0=tfe.Variable(initial_value=np.ones((8,1)))
    w0=None
    print(ps.virtual_memory().percent)
```

However the memory continues to climb. If I take the variable out of the loop and try and assign to the variable:

```
w0=tfe.Variable(initial_value=np.ones((8,1)))
for i in range (50000):
    w0.assign(np.zeros((8,1)))
    print(ps.virtual_memory().percent)
```

the memory appears to continue to climb. Lastly, I tried running the garbage collector on every iteration:

```
for i in range (50000):
    w0=tfe.Variable(initial_value=np.ones((8,1)))
    w0=None
    gc.collect()
    print(ps.virtual_memory().percent)
```

and I still get an increase in memory.

Is there something that I am missing or am I misunderstanding the possible use of the variable in eager execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a rather serious issue in eager execution, memory seems to be leaking rather abundantly.

You can find the related issue filed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19671). The workaround given there is:

> If you want a workaround in the meantime, `tf.set_random_seed(1)` will clear the kernel cache.

Comment: Thanks @P-Gn this appears to keep the memory at bay as a workaround. I appreciate the answer.