# Identify memory leak in tensorflow data pipeline and training?

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks, tensorflow-datasets

Memory Leaks With TF.Data.Dataset pipeline. Is there a profiler to identify the memory leaks in the pipeline or tf.keras training? 
Few questions if you have any thoughts – 
1.  Is there an obvious problem in the pseudo code that I am overlooking?
2.  Any thoughts on where/what to look for? 
3.  Any pointers to how to memory profile RAM usage as the training goes on to pin point problem?

I just moved my codebase to eager mode under Tensorflow 1.15 and I am running into memory issues that I didn’t have before. Before moving to eager mode, I could training for 500+ epocs without any issues and now, training stops after 70 epocs. I am trying to figure out a way to identify where the leak is and I was hoping some of you have some ideas.

I am using tf.data.Dataset to build the data pipeline (see pseudo code below) and to speed up the data feeding, I am using datasets with interleave as shown below. I have preprocessed data that is stored in sharded TFRecords files and the dataset API loads up data and does minimal processing to supply the appropriate batch sized data.  GPU memory seems fine and training goes on until the CPU RAM is completely depleted. As you see the table below, psutil memory log shows continuous increase of CPU RAM.

What I have tried: 
Explicitly call gc.collect, tf.set_random_seed(1) as suggested by these but none seems to help. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30324
[Memory Continually Increasing When Iterating in Tensorflow Eager Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267133/memory-continually-increasing-when-iterating-in-tensorflow-eager-execution)

Ubuntu 18.04, tf-nightly-gpu 1.15.0.dev20190728
CPU - AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X 12-Core Processor
RAM – 128GB
GPU - RTX 2080 Ti 11GB

```
#Generator that is passed to the fit_generator
    def get_simple_Dataset_generator(….):

    dataset = load_dataset (…)
          while True:
               try:
                 for x, Y in dataset:
                   yield x, Y
               finally:
                     dataset = load_dataset (“change data sources”)
                     #tried gc.collect(), tf.set_random_seed(1)

#sets up the dataset with interleave. 
def load_dataset(…):
   #setup etc
   dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: 
   tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(self.simple_gen_step1, 
                                output_types=(tf.string, tf.float32, tf.string), args=(x,batch_size, lstm_reshape,)),
                                cycle_length=2,
                                block_length=1)

    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda each_ticker, each_dataset, each_dates: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(self.simple_gen_step2, 
                                output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int16), args=(names, dataset, dates,batch_size,)),
                                cycle_length=2,
                                block_length=1)

  return dataset

#Our Model uses CuDNNLSTM and Dense layers
build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(feature_count,
                            batch_input_shape=(batch_size,look_back, feature_count),
                            stateful=Settings.get_config(Settings.STATEFUL), 
                            return_sequences=True))

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(feature_count, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(feature_count, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(feature_count, return_sequences = False))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense( max(feature_count//(2*1), target_classes), use_bias=False))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(max(feature_count//(2*2), target_classes),use_bias=False))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(max(feature_count//(2*3), target_classes), use_bias=False))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(target_classes, activation='softmax'))

    return model
```

CPU RAM Shown in psutil log

[image: CPU RAM Shown in psutil log]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into similar issue, I think there is a memory leak if class_weights are used in fit_generator. I have posted another one with more details.
[Using class_weights in fit_generator causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318714/using-class-weights-in-fit-generator-causes-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share what I have found regarding **memory leakage in TensorFlow 2.x.x**. It might not be a 100 % specific answer to your concrete questions but it might help others to solve their memory leakage issues when using **built-in functions like model.fit()**.

Here is a link to one of the related [GitHub issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31312) and here is my [solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31312#issuecomment-821809246) (please also cosider the comments to my solution).