# TensorFlow - Using class_weights in fit_generator causes memory leak

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In TensorFlow, when using class_weights in fit_generator causes the training process to continuously consume more and more CPU RAM until depletion. There is a stepped increased in memory usage after each epoch. See below for the reproducible example. To keep the reproducible example small, I decreased the size of the dataset and batch size, which shows the trend of increasing memory. While training with my actual data, it depletes the full 128GB RAM by 70 EPOCS.

Anyone ran into this problem or have any suggestions on this? My data has unbalanced data so I have to use class_weights but I cannot run the training for long with this.

In the code sample below, if you comment out the class weights, the program trains without depleting memory.

First image shows memory usage with class_weights while second one shows usage without class_weights.

[image: Memory Usage with class_weights]

[image: Memory usage without class_weights]

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adadelta


feature_count = 25
batch_size = 16
look_back = 5
target_groups = 10

def random_data_generator( ):
    x_data_size =(batch_size, look_back, feature_count) # batches, lookback, features
    x_data = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=5, size=x_data_size)

    y_data_size = (batch_size, target_groups)
    Y_data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=21, size=y_data_size)

    return x_data, Y_data

def get_simple_Dataset_generator():        
    while True:
        yield random_data_generator()

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(feature_count,
                    batch_input_shape=(batch_size,look_back, feature_count),
                    stateful=False))  
    model.add(Dense(target_groups, activation='softmax'))
    optimizer = Adadelta(learning_rate=1.0, epsilon=None) 
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer) 
    return model


def run_training():

    model = build_model()
    train_generator = get_simple_Dataset_generator()
    validation_generator = get_simple_Dataset_generator()
    class_weights = {0:2, 1:8, 2:1, 3:4, 4:8, 5:35, 6:30, 7:4, 8:5, 9:3}

    model.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=1,
            epochs=1000,            
            verbose=2,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=20,
            max_queue_size = 10,
            workers = 0, 
            use_multiprocessing = False,
            class_weight = class_weights
            )

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    run_training()
```

Answer (score 2):

For any future users, there seems to be a bug in the nightly build which seems to be fixed in the subsequent nightly builds. More details here in bug report.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31253

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved if you found the solution.

Comment: I am still facing this issue in Tensorflow 2.1.0, so most likely it is not definitely fixed.